# Assign variable with JSON string

Tags: ruby, json, string

I have a JSON string and I want to assign it to a variable. How can I do that?

```
my_var  = 'test text'
my_json = '{"text": "#{my_var}", "info": "great", "username": "Testuser", "avatar": "green"}'
```

does not work. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `"#{work}"` - allow interpolation
>
> `'#{not work}'` - not allow
>
> `' "#{not work}" '` - not allow
>
> `" '#{work}' "` - allow interpolation

[Ref](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#Interpolation)

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I was confused and thought the quotation marks of the value matters, not of the whole string.

Comment: Okay now it doesnt get recognized as valid JSON, so I need to escape the double quotation marks?

Comment: you can (read the ref) use an another notation like `%Q|"#{1+1}"| => "\"2\""`